# Send Data From Server (with valid IP) To Clients (with invalid IP) In the Internet By .Net Framework

Tags: c#, .net, ip, chat

I am writing an application for chat in the internet environment. In this application clients can chat together by connection to server and send messages through the server. If clients want to send data to the server there is not problem. Because server has a valid IP and is visible around the world. But if the sever wants to send data to the clients what happen in this point? Because the client's IP End-pint that I have in fact is the Endpoint of ISP Server.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a bit too broad. Read about sockets, TCP/IP and NAT/PAT. Using TCP a client connects to the server, then the server can send messages back over that connection.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the answer.